# How can I use the efficiency of numpy to calculate a matrix that is the subtraction of a vector with each of his values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

I have this vector

```
X=numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
```

And I want this matrix:

```
difX=([0,1,2,3],[-1,0,1,2],[-2,-1,0,1],[-3,-2,-1,0])
```

The easy way it is to program this nested cycle:

```
import numpy as np

X=numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
S=X.shape[0]
difx=np.empty((S,S))

for i in range(S):

    Xi=X[i]

    for j in range(S):

        Xj=X[j]
        difx[i,j]= Xi-Xj
```

However, I have a really big Vector and I don't want to use any cycles. I would like to use the efficiency of arrays modules of numpy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possibilities:

```
>>> X-X[:,None]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
>>> numpy.add.outer(-X, X)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
>>> numpy.subtract(*reversed(numpy.ix_(X, X)))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
>>> numpy.subtract.outer(X, X).T
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

Probably the shortest (assuming `numpy` imported as `np`):

```
>>> X-np.c_[X]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0]])
```

Timings:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100000)
>>> 
>>> timeit("numpy.add.outer(-X, X)", **kwds)
0.2078194150235504
>>> timeit("numpy.subtract.outer(X, X).T", **kwds)
0.1835216749459505
>>> timeit("X-X[:,None]", **kwds)
0.16011965298093855
>>> timeit("X-np.c_[X]", **kwds)
0.9050748841837049
>>> timeit("numpy.subtract(*reversed(numpy.ix_(X, X)))", **kwds)
0.7874130869749933
>>> timeit("X-X[None].T", **kwds)
0.1729387198574841
>>> timeit("X-X.reshape(-1,1)", **kwds)
0.16520787891931832
```

For larger `X` these differences become negligible:

```
X = np.repeat(X, 100)
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=1000)
>>>
>>> timeit("X-np.atleast_2d(X).T", **kwds)
0.20351033308543265
>>> timeit("numpy.add.outer(-X, X)", **kwds)
0.20114074111916125
>>> timeit("numpy.subtract.outer(X, X).T", **kwds)
0.19854155299253762
>>> timeit("numpy.subtract(*reversed(numpy.ix_(X, X)))", **kwds)
0.20600174297578633
>>> timeit("X-np.c_[X]", **kwds)
0.2087497659958899
>>> timeit("X-X[:,None]", **kwds)
0.20137557992711663
>>> timeit("X-X[None].T", **kwds)
0.19664623402059078
>>> timeit("X-X.reshape(-1,1)", **kwds)
0.201627325033769
```

Comment: Epic, thank you. I really suggest you test the speed.

Comment: @HolyCrack Done.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use broadcasting and new axes:

```
X[None,:]-X[:,None]
```

Comment: Cool, I've try to do that but failed. Nice to see it done !

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test the speed difference but this should work:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib

X = np.array([1,2,3,4])

print(np.matlib.repmat(X, 4, 1) - np.matlib.repmat(X.reshape(4,1), 1, 4))
```